# Yolov3 on one class of COCO Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo

I want to compare the performance of a yolov3 model that can detect multiple classes with a yolov3 model that can only detect one class.

**What I've done so far:**

- For comparison I use the yolov3 model which is pretrained on the COCO dataset.
  So I use the yolov3.cfg coco.data and the yolov3.weights files which are mentioned here: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/
- Then I've downloaded the train and val data for a specific class from the COCO Website. ~6400 train images and ~2600 validation data for the class person and ~12744 train images and ~580 validation images for the class chair.
- for the one-class models i have modified the yolov3.cfg in the corresponding lines (#classes=1 and #filters=18)
- I then have trained a yolov3 model for each (person and chair) based on the pretrained weights file: darknet53.conv.74

**Training**

- I have trained the model for the class person for about **267100** batches. **(AVG-LOSS: 1.3)**
- I have trained model for the class chair for about **51200** batches. **(AVG-LOSS: 1.0)**

**Validation**

- I've used the downloaded validation images to calculate the map-value/ap-value. I've done this by calling `darknet detector map model.data model.cfg model.best.weights`

**class person**

- When I use the default coco model, which can detect 80 classes, I get:

  `class_id = 0, name = person, ap = 76.56%, (TP=7684, FP=3982)`
- The trained one-class model achieves:

  `class_id = 0, name = person, ap = 66.63%, (TP=6515, FP=2259)`

**class chair**

- When I use the default coco model, which can detect 80 classes, I get:

  `class_id = 0, name = person, ap = 60.58%, (TP=880, FP=504)`
- The trained one-class model achieves:

  `class_id = 0, name = person, ap = 38.59%, (TP=482, FP=232)`

**Questions**

1. Why is the avg-loss during training still above 1.0? It looks like the function already has converged and I'm already above the rule of thumb of ~2000 batches per class.
2. Shouldn't the amount of data beeing enough for the training of only one class? Especially when I use pretrained weights fo the conv-layers?
3. Are the average precision (ap) values realistic? Is correct that the one-class models perform worse than the model which is trained with all 80 classes? If not, what could be the reasons why the precision of the one-class model is worse?
4. If yes, is this due to the fact that if we train with all classes we really can learn the differences between the classes and that results in a better performance that just learning only one class?

Train image of class chair

[image: Train image of class chair]

Train image of class person

[image: Train image of class person]

Comment: Any suggestions?:/

Comment: It is really hard to say what is happening. Maybe the network is just more refined because it saw more and more different data. Are you sure the datasets for the individual classes are fine, not that you have like no chair on 50% of the chair images and so they only add noise to the training.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are fine. I downloaded them like described in this blog:https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/271. That means I look for the ID for the class chair and select all images of the coco dataset where this ID occurs and also download annotations of this ( and only this) ID

Comment: Here is a post that might be relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881576/understanding-how-yolo-is-trained