# Understanding How YOLO is trained

Tags: keras, deep-learning, yolo

I'm trying to understand how YOLO (v2) is trained. To do so, I'm using this keras implementation https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2 to train YOLO from scratch on VOC dataset (I'm open to other implementation, but I never worked with pytorch, so, keras implementation will be first choice).

1- As I understood YOLO, it is first trained for classification on imageNet, then these trained weights (for classification) should be use somewhere when training yolo for regression (to detect bounding boxes). In most code I found on internet to train yolo from scratch (for regression), I don't see the part where these classification weight are loaded. When does this happen? when are the classification weights used in training yolo regression?

2- Is my understanding as described in 1) correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Use pre-trained weights for the whole detector (backend + frontend , i.e. the classification network + the detector).
- Use pre-trained weights for the backend only.

All is explained bellow https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2#2-edit-the-configuration-file on the link you gave.

In the code, loading of pre-trained weights for the whole model is done [here](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/8bc3fcdc123a5d6b9624ed4188e07b876b79dac5/train.py#L73). It is optional.

Pre-trained weights for backend is mandatory (according to the tutorial), in the code it is done [here](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/8bc3fcdc123a5d6b9624ed4188e07b876b79dac5/backend.py#L167) (example for full Yolo). Note that you should have downloaded the backend weights before creating the model as stated in the tutorial or at the beginning of the [file](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/8bc3fcdc123a5d6b9624ed4188e07b876b79dac5/backend.py#L11).

#### Edit 1

If your number of classes changes, the number of filters in the detector part (the front-end) will change as the classification vector size changes. However the back-end (the feature extractor, i.e the backbone) stays the same even if the number of classes changes.

You can use pre-trained any pre-trained weights that match the size for the backbone, but for the whole network you cannot if the number of classes varies. For instance you cannot use the Racoon's weights for a dog and cat detector.

You cannot use YoloV2 original weights to initialise this network because the format is different between Darknet and Keras, you first have to translate them into Keras format.

It's fine to use only backbone pre-trained weights if you have enough training data.

Note that there is an additional option called transfert learning. If you have a pre-trained networks (backbone and front-end) you can extract the backbone weights and use them to initialise your network backbone.

#### Edit 2

No, front-end and backend are not strictly speaking two separate networks: they are two chained networks. In fact in most deep learning frameworks such as PyTorch, Keras or Tensorflow, any layer can be considered as a network (Fully Connected, Convolutive, MaxPool, ...).

A "networks" is just an object that represents an arbitrary complex mathematical function mapping inputs to outputs on which Automatic Differentiation can be applied (you must define forward and backward propagation).

In a single shot object detector such as Yolo it more relevant to think about the whole network as the chain of two networks: the **backbone** and the **detector**. This representation allows more generic construct and a wider variety of tuning (i.e use a more performant backbone or a lightweight one).

Yes you are right, bounding box regression and label classification happened at the very end of the whole networks, hence in the front-end.

The front-end can have an arbitrary number of layers, the only constraint is in its last layer which should respect a specific channel size (i.e a given number of filters) that is always constrained by the number of classes you want classify.

Usually the number of channels in the last output layer should be `numberOfClasses + 4` where `numberOfClasses` includes the background class and where the number 4 represents the four coordinates of the bounding box. This example is simplified a lot, I advice you to read Yolo papers to have a better understanding of the network structure.

It appears that there is only one trainable layer (a 2D Conv [here](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/8bc3fcdc123a5d6b9624ed4188e07b876b79dac5/frontend.py#L63)) in the detector network. Note the size of the output that is constrained by the number of classes: `self.nb_box * (4 + 1 + self.nb_class)`.

This layer parameters are then initialised with a random distribution.

Concerning your last question I think you are correct about the procedure for transfert learning, that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1) Regarding pre-trained weights for backend. Can I use weights provided on the yoloV2 website? The experiencor's tutorial provides some weights but they are trained on raccon data. I want to train yolo for only some object of the VOC dataset.

2) Let say I want to train Yolo on only "dog" and "cat". If I want to modify/reduce the yolo architecture (because I am training on only 2 objects) then I can't use pre-trained weights, right? because the architecture of pre-trained weight and my newly created architecture will not match, so I need to train from scratch, right?

Comment: I added details in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding more informations, that helped me a lot. I was thinking Backend and Frontend are two separate networks, but it is not right? Both are 1 network. Backend is just the feature extractor part of the network and Frontend the detector part. 1) so regression for bounding box prediction happens in frontend right? 2) how many layers does frontend has? only one, which is initialized [here](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/master/frontend.py#L74)?

Comment: 3) Regarding transfer learning and yoloV2 original weight: That is exactly what I was meaning, I took yoloV2 original weight, convert it into keras, then remove the last layers. Doing so, it seems that the remaining networks size (after removing last layer) match the backend size from experiencor, which is created [here](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/8bc3fcdc123a5d6b9624ed4188e07b876b79dac5/backend.py#L36). Is this a correct procedure?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. So if my understanding is correct: 1) In the architecture build by experiencor: the backend/backbone represent about (let say) 95% of the network and consist of extracting features for the classification task. The front-end, which performs regression for bounding boxes prediction (as well as the final classification I presume) represent only a small part (let say 5%) of the network. Is this a common practice in single-shot detector networks? Is this the case in YOLO?

Comment: Almost: the backbone computes features relevant both for classification and regression (and more generally for any task it is trained to) and the front-end do the « formatting » to output class and boxes.

Comment: And yes, usually the front-end is smaller. For Yolo it depends the version (actually there is 3 versions) but there are one ore two layers for the front end as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

**I will address the 2nd part of your question first**

In Object detection when an image is labelled, a label file is generated that contains the bounding box co-ordinates and the classification/class of the object/objects.

In **experiencor** code the pre-trained weights that are loaded are not classification weights but they have both co-ordinates as well as class names for objects in each image converted into weights.
Once you have them or train the model from scratch using the label files, the model gets trained using both the images and the corresponding label file containing bounding box co-ordinates and class names for the objects in the images.

So here classification and regression training happens together.

Feel free to comment if you have doubts and give tick if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It brought me some light on the topic. I could find these xml's Annotations file (in the VOC dataset), where bounding boxes and labels are already gave for each image. Both (bounding boxes and labels) represent the true label/response of my supervised learning problem. So I can train from scratch using it (if my understanding is correct). Now what I does not understand, is why do I need pre-trained weight?

Comment: please accept the answer or upvote if you find the answer useful...and comment if you have any further doubts